# Change default unit for measure tool

Tags: qgis, measurements

Every time I open the measure tool in QGIS 3.28 I change the units to feet but it defaults back to meters. I tried settings -> options -> map tools & updated preferred distance units to feet, but measure tool still opens up in meters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If not already done go to Project Properties ->General  and set the units distance for measurement to feet and see if that work

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks!